# Как сравнить два слова с разным регистром Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне дали задачу - написать небольшую программу которая принимает зарание неизвестное количество строк из которых нужно взять слова с **заглавными** буквами, и впереди указать их порядковый номер через дефис.

Казалось бы дело на минут 40, не больше. Но тут программка неожиданна начала тупить и регисты сравнивать отказалась.

```
import sys

    words = list()
    words1 = list()
    n = 0

    for i in sys.stdin:
        i = i.rstrip('\n')
        words.append(i)

    words2 = [words for words in enumerate(words)]

    for j in words2:
        if j[1] == j[1][0].upper():
            words1.append(j)

    #  print(0)
    #  print(words1)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from re import compile

words = compile(r'[^\s\d]{2,}')
capital_letter = compile(r'[A-ZА-Я]\S+')

words_list = words.findall(sys.stdin.read())
print(*["%d\t%s" % (words_list.index(w) + 1, w) for w in words_list if capital_letter.match(w)], sep="\n")
```

Если в качестве входных данных взять текст этого запроса, то на выходе получим следующее:

```
1   Мне
27  Казалось
34  Но
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

ws = ('{} - {}'.format(n, w) for n, w in enumerate(i.strip() for i in sys.stdin) if w.isupper())
print(*ws, sep='\n')
```